# If $ax^2+(b+c)x+d+e=0$ has roots greater than $1$, then show that $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ has at least one real root

Tags: induction, roots, quadratics

Your are given an equation
$$
ax^2+(b+c)x+d+e=0
$$
whose roots are real and  greater than $1,$ show that the equation
$$
ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e
$$
has at least one real root. Note that $a,b,c,d,e$ are all real numbers.

I have tried to solve this question using the method of contradiction. However I was not able to make great progress. Is there any way I can solve it using the method of contradiction or any other proof strategy. I would also love to see an approach using predicate logic (only if it's possible).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Can you please review my question after this edit?Thanks

Comment: It's a bit better.

Comment: What has your question to do with `induction`?

Comment: The identical question posted after this has an answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3807165/if-ax2cbxed-0-has-real-roots-greater-than-1-show-that-ax4bx3cx