# If $ax^2+(c+b)x+e+d=0$ has real roots greater than $1$, show that $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ has at least one real root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> If $a, b, c, d ,e$ are real numbers such that the equation $ax^2 +(c+b)x+e+d = 0$ has real roots greater than $1$, show that the equation $ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$ has at least one real root.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker know about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort tends to give the wrong impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Same question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3807135/how-to-draw-conclusions-about-roots-of-a-biquadratic-equation-when-we-are-given ?

Comment: @enzotib Not been answered, but yes, same question all right!

Answer (score 4):

Let $\rho > 1$ be a root of the first equation and pick a $y$ such as $y^2 = \rho$ and set $f(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$. Now we have:

$$\begin{align}
f(y) &= ay^4 + by^3 + cy^2 + dy + e \\
     &= a\rho ^2 + b\rho y +c\rho +dy + e\\
     &= a\rho ^2 + b\rho y +c\rho +dy + e + b\rho - b\rho + d - d\\
     &= (a\rho ^2 + b\rho +c\rho +d + e) + b\rho y - b\rho + dy - d\\
     &= 0 + b\rho (y-1) + d(y-1)\\
     &= (y-1)(b\rho + d)
\end{align}$$

If $(b\rho + d) = 0$ we have found a root. Assume the contrary. Then,

$$\begin{align}
f(\sqrt{\rho})f(-\sqrt{\rho}) &= (\sqrt{\rho}-1)(b\rho + d)(-\sqrt{\rho}-1)(b\rho + d) \\
&= (1-\rho)(b\rho + d)^2 < 0
\end{align}$$

Since $f$ is a polynomial it is continuous in $\left[-\sqrt{\rho},\sqrt{\rho}\right]$ so we can apply Bolzano's theorem and we are done.